# How to reduce hash value's length?

Tags: hash

I'd like to squeeze or compress the result hash value from MD5 or SHA1 at a server side application so that at the client can decompress it or desqueeze it  , is this possible ? its a usability issue for my application.

Comment: For example : your going to send your One time password which is a result of a hash value, it would be so hard for the user to write 32 bytes ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, hash values cannot be compressed. By design their bits are highly random and have maximum entropy, so there is no redundancy to compress.

If you want to make the hash values easier to read for users you can use different tricks, such as:

- **Displaying fewer digits.** Instead of 32 digits just show 16.
- **Using a different base.** For instance, if you used base 62 using all the uppercase and lowercase letters plus numbers 0-9 as digits then you could show a 128-bit hash using 22 letters+digits versus 32 hex digits:

  > log<sub>62</sub> (2<sup>128</sup>) ≈ 21.5
- **Adding whitespace or punctuation.** You'll commonly see CD keys printed with dashes like AX7T4-BZ41O-JK3FF-QOZ96. It's easier for users to read this than 20 digits all jammed together.

Comment: In case of anything like "using all digits plus uppercase and lowercase letters" I would highly recommend to not use groups that look similar, e.g. [ 0 (zero), o (small o) and O (uppercase o) ]. I would simply avoid using characters from those groups altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Hash values are quite short; attempting compression on these (quite random and highly varied) values is difficult and inefficient. If you want to save space, truncating the value could help, but keep in mind that if you do this, you increase collision space (and decrease key space).