# Reduce MD5 - Using a different base

Tags: php, hash, radix

My client generates promotional coupon codes which are nothing but 32 char MD5 hashes.

My job is to reduce the MD5 string from 32 chars to less than 10 chars in a way that the hash can be recreated from the reduced string.

The reduction is important as it would be easier for users to reproduce the reduced hash.

For e.g.: `719bedacf2e560b27f39d80accc67ffd => ZjKa1Gh` (not mathematically true)

I came across this: [How to reduce hash value's length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116631/how-to-reduce-hash-values-length)

It suggests: **Using a different base**

I am clueless as to how to do this in PHP, can we decode a string to its ASCII and re-encode it?

Are there any in-built functions in PHP that I can use in this case?

> Update using https://packagist.org/packages/aza/math

```
$original = '719bedacf2e560b27f39d80accc67ffd';
$long1 = NumeralSystem::convert($original, 16, 10);
$short = NumeralSystem::convertTo($long1, 62);
$long2 = NumeralSystem::convertFrom($short, 62);
$recovered = NumeralSystem::convert($long2, 10, 16);

var_dump($long1);
var_dump($short);
var_dump($long2);
var_dump($recovered);

// output
string(39) "151012390170261082849236619706853916669"
string(22) "3SNOKWefotgnnCmWnYkTOf"
string(39) "151012390170261082849236619706853916669"
string(32) "719bedacf2e560b27f39d80accc67ffd"
```

Seems like the lowest I can reach from 32 chars MD5 is 22 chars this way. I am still looking for ways in which I can further reduce it to 10 chars.

> Update: Using first half of MD5

```
$original = '719bedacf2e560b';
$coupon = NumeralSystem::convert($original, 16, 62);
$recovered = NumeralSystem::convert($coupon, 62, 16);

var_dump($coupon);
var_dump($recovered);

// output
string(10) "bnMR3RjZil"
string(15) "719bedacf2e560b"
```

If the user is providing `bnMR3RjZil` I can use that to recreate `719bedacf2e560b` and then do a MySQL `LIKE` search to get the full MD5. If it returns a row I can then get forward with the promotional activity.

Comment: It is unclear what you are exactly trying to do. There is no way to reduce a given md5 hash "to its ASCII", what should that mean? The hash already is in ASCII encoding.

Comment: I meant to ask if the string can be reduced to its ASCII in PHP, in a sense that if there is `A` I get `065` as output.
If I can get `065` then I can store it in a different way.

Comment: Ah, you mean the character codes. You are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php, but I doubt that will bring you forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cryptographic hash is in fact a sequence of bits but it can be interpreted as a number. As such, you could theoretically use good old [base_convert()](http://php.net/base_convert) to express is in a large base. Unfortunately, this function only works up to base 36 and it's restricted to actual numbers (i.e. short integers that fit into `PHP_INT_MAX`)—otherwise data loss happens.

Here's where third-party libraries come to the rescue. The only problem is that they tend to be difficult to find because they normally address very specific use cases (Bitcoin, ID obfuscation, etc.).

I found e.g. [aza/math](https://packagist.org/packages/aza/math), which is probably overkill but should get the job done. I haven't had the chance of testing it but it should go like this:

```
$original = '719bedacf2e560b27f39d80accc67ffd';
$short = NumeralSystem::convert($original, 16, 62);
$recovered = NumeralSystem::convert($short, 62, 16);
```

Answer (score 4):

> My job is to reduce the MD5 string from 32 chars to less than 10 chars in a way that the hash can be recreated from the reduced string.

That isn't possible. A MD5 hash is 128 bits; an ASCII character is 7 bits. There's no way to store an MD5 hash in any less than 128÷7 = 18.2 (round up to 19) ASCII characters, and even that would include nonprintable control characters.

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I am sure you can't convert MD5 to ASCII. I am asking if I can break down the MD5 hash into 32 different characters, and then find the ASCII of each of the 32 chars, maybe I can reintegrate them using a higher base.

Comment: Base conversion doesn't make a difference here. There's only 7 bits of information in an ASCII character, no matter how you slice it. (In a sense, using ASCII this way is essentially converting the data to base 128.)

Answer (score 1):

The method of using a different base could proceed as follows. Note that the code below is just to illustrate the method, in order to implement it efficiently, one would need to work directly with the binary representation.

The idea is that you interpret your input string as a sequence of 128 bits. Now, if you specify that your new alphabet (characters of the new base system) is `A-Za-z0-9+-`, you have 64 characters which means that you need 6 bits to encode each one of them. Therefore you can first convert your input string to binary representation, split this representation into chunks of 6 bits, and express each chunk within the specified character set `A-Za-z0-9+-`:

```
<?php

$s = "719bedacf2e560b27f39d80accc67ffd";

function conv($s){
  $ret = base_convert($s, 16, 2);
  return str_repeat("0", 8 - strlen($ret)) . $ret;
}

$binary_repr = implode(array_map(conv, str_split($s, 2)), '');

$items = str_split($binary_repr, 6);

function item2char($str){
  $code = base_convert($str, 2, 10);
  $alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-';
  return $alphabet[$code];
}

$result = implode(array_map(item2char, $items), '');
echo $result;

?>
```

As noted in the comments, this is basically the idea behind:

```
<?php
$s = "719bedacf2e560b27f39d80accc67ffd";

echo base64_encode(hex2bin($s));
//cZvtrPLlYLJ/OdgKzMZ//Q==

echo bin2hex(base64_decode("cZvtrPLlYLJ/OdgKzMZ//Q=="));
//719bedacf2e560b27f39d80accc67ffd

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think this is a great start, I can work on it to suit my specific needs.

Comment: What you're describing already has a name and an implementation in PHP -- it's Base64. `base64_encode(md5($input, true))`.

Comment: @duskwuff yes, I wanted to illustrate the method, I modified the answer